# vshost.exe stopped working with error: 'An invalid handle was specified'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, kinect-sdk

I am using .Net Framework 4.5, in Visual Studio 2013, for re-programming the Kinect.
I am able to build my code perfectly but, somehow, inside my application, I need to use the "WPFFolderBrowser.dll".

What happens is that, in the moment I push the button for doing this Debugging process online (i.e for searching folders), the program crashes!

> Error:bin\x64\Release\WPFFolderBrowser.dll'. Cannot find or open the
>   PDB file. The thread 0x1250 has exited with code 259 (0x103). The
>   program '[4400] KinectTracker.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited
>   with code 0 (0x0). The program '[4400] KinectTracker.vshost.exe' has
>   exited with code -1073741816 (0xc0000008) 'An invalid handle was
>   specified'.

The WPFFolderBrowser.dll exists inside the folder.

Searching on-line, I thought this was a Debugging problem about Microsoft Symbol Servers!
I've already downloaded this symbols, enabled their use and still nothing.
(tools -- options -- debugging -- symbols -- enable Microsfot Symbol Servers and nothing)

Also done:

> tools -- options -- debugging -- general -- enable .Net framework
>   source stepping

but still error.

Re-installed the VS 2013, nothing.
Changed to .Net 4.5.1, nothing.
Run VS as administrator, nothing.

At the same time, my teammate is using the same code, vs 2013 also, .net 4.5 and has no error!

I really need help! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER GUYS

I went on removing some Microsoft Components, maybe that were from automatic updates that I haven't checked and the error has gone away.

The part "Cannot find or open the PDB file." also gone away in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You have this tagged under kinect-sdk but I don't quite think this is a Kinect SDK issue. Have you tried the solution posted here:
[Why is Visual Studio 2010 not able to find/open PDB files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813975/why-is-visual-studio-2010-not-able-to-find-open-pdb-files)