# Long WPF C# Start Up Time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, launch

I recently got a new PC, and installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.
When I start ANY WPF application (even a freshly-created new WPF Project) it takes long time to launch it, even if i'm double-clicking it from windows explorer, not from Visual Studio.

When i'm launching the application I recieve some weird things on the Output window in Visual Studio, and after 10-15 secs the application starts.

Here's the output:

> 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'.
>   'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe):
>
> Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe):  'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CLIENTDIAGNOSTICS\XAMLDIAGNOSTICS\x86\WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: PythonServerGUI.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.

It says I have some missing dlls, I guess it has some connection to the long start-up time, but i'm not sure.

Thanks to the helpers! :)

Comment: Worth a shot to see if you might be facing binding issues - these are usually the prime suspects, right off the bat... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx

Comment: Not missing DLLs, It's looking for PDB 'program database' files. They store debugging information.

Comment: Go to your references and reload or refresh it, I forgot the term for it. But it is something to fix the References. The update for VC Community edition mentioned about this problem and it was fixed, if your's is not updated. The work around is re launch VS and re build. Avoid Re-targeting of Framework on VS 2015 community, it is buggy.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813975/why-is-visual-studio-2010-not-able-to-find-open-pdb-files